# correct coding structure in React.js?

Tags: javascript, react.js

I'm new to react and I'm still using the life cycle methods, so my question is since `componentDidMount()` acts like a constructor I'm planning to initialize everything there:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className="done-container" style={this.style().taskContainer}>
                <span style={this.style().title}>Done</span>
                {
                    this.props.done.map((d) => (

                    <div className={`done ${this.state.isActive ? 'active' : ''}`} id={this.props.done.id}
                    onClick={(e) => {
                        this.props.setTaskID(d.id);
                        this.setToActive(e); //3.Call <-----
                        this.props.arrowStyleToDone();
                    }}>

                    </div>

                    ))
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

    setToActive  //1.Declare <----
    componentDidMount() {
        //2.Initialize  <-----
        this.setToActive = (e) => {
            if(!e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
                e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
                e.currentTarget.classList.add('border-done')
                this.props.closeAllTasks();
                this.props.closeAllDoing();
            } else {
                e.currentTarget.classList.remove('active');
                e.currentTarget.classList.remove('border-done')
                this.props.disableArrowButton();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is that if I declare everything inside the class which looks very ugly in my opinion, but then initializing everything on `componentDidMount()` my web app will be faster because it won't need to declare and initialize everything every render.

Is this correct? and should I put the declaring and initialization on top of `render()`? but the `componenDidMount()` is called after the initial render.

Comment: Can I suggest reducing your indent size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifecycle hooks are functions that are invoked at different stages of a component. Here `constructor()` and `componentDidMount()` works different. From my point of view, `state` variables are initialized inside `constructor()` and api calls are done in `componentDidMount()` hook. we are not supposed to define function definitions inside lifecycle hooks. Your above component can be converted to

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isActive: false
    };
  }

  setToActive = (e, id) => {
    const {
      setTaskID,
      arrowStyleToDone,
      closeAllTasks,
      closeAllDoing,
      disableArrowButton
    } = this.props;
    setTaskID(id);
    arrowStyleToDone();
    if (!e.target.classList.contains("active")) {
      e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
      e.currentTarget.classList.add("border-done");
      closeAllTasks();
      closeAllDoing();
    } else {
      e.currentTarget.classList.remove("active");
      e.currentTarget.classList.remove("border-done");
      disableArrowButton();
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {} // no need for this lifecycle since we are not making any initial function call, like fetch from api etc.

  render() {
    const { done } = this.props;
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="done-container" style={this.style().taskContainer}>
        <span style={this.style().title}>Done</span>
        {done &&
          done.map(item => (
            <div
              className={`done ${isActive ? "active" : ""}`}
              key={item.id}
              onClick={e => this.setToActive(e, item.id)}
            ></div>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Basic structure of React component is

Class component

```
class Class_Name extends Component{
    constructor(){
      this.state = {} // state variable
      this.toggleTab = this.toggleTab.bind(this);
    }

   // other functions
   toggleTab = ()=>{} // these are example functions.

   // life cycle hooks if you are using any

   render(){
    return (

    )

   }


}
```

Comment: thank you, I guess I'm just going to use componentDidMount() for http requests, then define functions in the class but outside the render().

Comment: @KevinBryan exactly thats how you do, you can reach me at anytime. will update if I am free